# Appium treating visibility of buttons differently

Tags: ios, appium

I have two buttons in my aspx page.

button 1

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Main$Main$Main$customerPage$btnCustomerNewCustomerQuote" value="Quote" onclick="schCust.btnCustomerNewCustomerQuote_onclick(); return false;" id="btnCustomerNewCustomerQuote" title="new quote">
```

button 2

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Main$Main$Main$customerPage$btnCustomerNewCustomer" value="Appt" onclick="schCust.btnCustomerNewCustomer_onclick(); return false;" id="btnCustomerNewCustomer" title="new Appointment">
```

the problem is the appium inspector xml reads button 1 as visible while button 2 as not visible.

```
<UIAButton name="Quote" label="New Customer - Quote" value="" dom="[object Object]" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Create a new customer quote" path="/0/0/1/1/4" x="909.0000013113407" y="599.0000397336529" width="26.00000607588322" height="139.00000113649605">
</UIAButton>

<UIAButton name="Appt" label="New Customer - Appt" value="" dom="[object Object]" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="Create a new customer and appointment" path="/0/0/1/1/5" x="908.9999952354575" y="745.0000397336527" width="26.00000576990351" height="132.00000113649605">
```

I am using
Appium 1.4.13

iOS: 9.1

xcode: 7.2

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: are you sure the `UIAButton name="Appt"` button has not been hidden in the code apart from aspx?